# Proving uniform convergence of sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ with $f(1)=0.$
How can I show that the sequence $\{x^nf(x)\}$ converges uniformly on $ [0,1]$?

Can I deduce that $f(x)$ is bounded? Then I can get $lim_{n \to \infty} x^nf(x)=0.$

Please help...

Comment: For the proof of uniform convergence, [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273539/prove-that-this-function-sequence-converges-uniformly?rq=1) can be referred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you can show that $f$ is bounded on $[0,1].$

First observe that $[0,1]$ is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R$ hence it is compact by
Heine Borel theorem.

Now, we know that continuous image of a compact set is compact. Hence image of
$f$ on $[0,1]$ is compact and hence again closed and bounded as you want.

Let $ g_n(x) $ = $x^nf(x)$. then since $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$, therefore $g_n(x)$ are also bounded and $\lim_{n\to \infty}x^nf(x)$=0 on $[0,1].$ (becuase, at $x=1$ , $f(x)=0$).

Comment: it's not clear enough to me , i think we get point wise convergent and we still need to prove: sup(x^nf(x))-->0 in order to get uniform convergence @VikrantDesai

Comment: I got it, thanks for providing me your answer